# Complexity analysis of separability in the multipartite case

Tags: entanglement, resource-request, complexity-theory

It's well known that determining whether a bipartite mixed state is separable or entangled is a $\mathsf{NP}$-hard problem under some accuracy estimates (cf. this [TCS SE discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32122)). Now I'm curious whether there exist detailed treatises on the complexity analysis of various possible cases of complete<sup>1</sup> and partial separability of multipartite (pure and mixed) states.

Could someone provide some insight into this? Say, is there any specific case of partial separability, determining which would be a problem in $\mathsf{P}$ rather than in $\mathsf{NP}$?

<sup>1: For complete separability, I believe the same arguments apply as for the bipartite case, [as mentioned by Norbert Schuch](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32122/how-does-one-determine-if-a-mixed-bipartite-quantum-state-is-entangled-or-not#comment73436_32158). However, it'd be interesting to look at partial separability too.</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by "partial separability"? As soon as you group the multipartite state into two (or more) blocks, you just reduce to the bipartite case again.